# Enzyme element.props() in react native testing library

Tags: unit-testing, enzyme, react-testing-library, react-native-testing-library

I need to refactor all enzyme unit test to react native testing library.

In Enzyme, to get the props of the children elements I can use some thing like :

`((rootElement.props() as Props).prop).toBe(value)`.

The prop() function returns the props hash for the current node of the wrapper. NOTE: can only be called on a wrapper of a single node.

How can I do the same in react native testing library ?

Should I only pass the full path to the prop? like this:

```
expect(nextUpNoThanksButton[0].props.children.props.isSelected).toEqual(true);
```

Or is there another way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

The very fundamental tenet of React Testing Library is to **not** test if a component received props or do any sort of assertions with props, state etc.

Hence, I don't think it's possible to do what you need in RTL in this case.

And this ideology goes a long way in writing better unit tests.

While enzyme gives these options, and in some cases, they are helpful, it can be argued that it makes for a way to make improper assertions and eventually beat the very purpose of unit tests.

Verify *what* happens after you pass some set of props. That is, what happens on the DOM. Because eventually, that is what matters, and you are asserting what happens in the real world from an end user's perspective. And this is the point which RTL promotes.

You can always do things like,

- Assert if a function was called. Pass a function callback as prop and then you can verify if it's been called.
- Assert that some other action happened which is an effect of passing a specific prop.
- Assert things getting shown or not shown on the DOM as an effect of a prop.

We have gone through the same process where out entire unit tests suites were built using Enzyme. We eventually decided to move to RTL and roughly this is the approach we have followed,

- Any new unit tests being written, should use RTL. No exceptions.
- Any existing unit tests which used Enzyme, can remain. They would still run and do their job.
- Every once in a while, as part of general code changes, we would try and pick up enzyme based unit tests and convert them. Based on complexity this exercise can take time. But you can start with low hanging fruits and work your way up to more complex ones and convert them methodically to use RTL.

Hope this helps.